# Shifting overlay position every x seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

Currently, I add a watermark to the bottom right of my video to prevent others from republishing it. However, they blur the watermark so I'm thinking of adding a moving watermark that changes its position every x seconds.

Below is my current ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=iw/4:ow*90/272[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=W-w-W*10/100:H-h-H*5/100" -preset veryfast output.mp4`

How can I make the watermark position from the bottom right to top right, to top left, and bottom left every 30 seconds? Thank you.

Comment: See the 2nd command in my answer at https://superuser.com/q/1413085

Comment: Thank you @Gyan for the answer! I get the idea of changing x and y now. Still I don't understand the use of `5+mod(trunc(((t-12)+1200)/1200),2)` so I don't know what to change to get the result I want. Sorry I'm not familiar with code and command, I was just guessing. Could you please explain what does that mean?

I tried to have the position change every 60 seconds with this:

`overlay='5+mod(trunc(((t-12)+12)/12),2)*(W-w-W*10/100)':'5+mod(trunc(((t-12)+18)/12),2)*(H-h-H*5/100)':enable='gt(t,12)'`

(please read the next comment I have to split it due to the limitation)

Comment: However, the position changed every 6 seconds. Also only the bottom watermarks were perfectly positioned. The top watermarks stuck near the video frame without any spaces. How can I make the top left mirror the bottom left, and the top right mirror the bottom right? Sorry again for my noob question.

Comment: I'll add an answer over the next couple of days.

Comment: Thanks Gyan. Looking forward to your answer! In the meantime I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

The overlay expression, for changing every 30 seconds is,

```
overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t\,120)\,60)\,W-w-W*10/100\,W*10/100)':y='if(lt(mod(t+30\,120)\,60)\,H-h-H*5/100\,H*5/100)'
```

This will start from bottom-right and shift clockwise every 30 seconds.

The 2nd arg (120) in the mod function is the period of one rotation. `60` is half-period.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried to make it work but was only able to change the time.